# Renaming a file using Dropbox API Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

I haven't found the correct way to do this. I could recreate the file and upload it with the new name, and then I would just delete the file with the old name, but this doesn't seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
NSString *fromPath = <old_path>
NSString *toPath   = <new_path>
BRestClient *dbClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
[dbClient moveFrom:fromPath toPath:toPath];
```

Comment: It would seem unfair if I told you I had already found out that solution, so... I won't say it. Thanks!